# Open Google Maps navigation in Picture and Picture Mode

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-intent

I have a simple intent to run google maps navigation - it works really well. It automatically switches to bicycle mode and does not require any confirmation from user, just starts navigating.
My code looks like this:

```
    try {
        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + lastPoint.latitude + "," + lastPoint.longitude + "&mode=b");
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        startActivity(mapIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now, how can I modify this intent to run navigation in picture-in-picture mode by default (ofc it must be available in the system and enabled for google maps app)? My app does not use PiP by itself, if it's your concern.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this official guide [PiP Support](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture#java)

As shown in the article,
First you may need to declare PiP support in androidmanifest.xml like this

```
<activity android:name="VideoActivity"
android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
```

and then

```
@Override
public void onActionClicked(Action action) {
  if (action.getId() == R.id.lb_control_picture_in_picture) {
    getActivity().enterPictureInPictureMode();
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: But it's not 'my' activity. It's a separate intent from Google Maps app.

Comment: In that case, I hardly believe that's possible. Because google map only enters into PiP mode when user has started navigation and presses Home button. Ans when you'll call the Intent, you'd be only giving route information. So, unless user presses start button in their google map afterwards and then home, we could not open it to PiP mode.